# How to restrict access to files in Drupal 7 only to authenticated users

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

I am looking for a solution to create a list of files in D7 but only allow them to be seen (and downloaded) by authenticated users.

In this way only users that I, as admin, add will be able to view the list of files and download them.

While searching I found references to a module called content_access but it has not seen any updates for the past year.

Anyone with references or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Uploading and Storage**

Enable and use private file storage. *[Full documentation from excerpt below...](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file)*

> The Upload destination by default only has the public files option
>   available – making the files available right from the server (without
>   Drupal checking any access). If you want to use private files, you
>   must first change some settings at the file system administration page
>   (Administer > Configuration > Media: File system). See below for
>   details.

There is additional overhead when you use private file storage, but this should accomplish what you need it to.

[image: Private File Storage Settings]

---

**Listing and Downloading**

To generate a protected list of downloadable files you could use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views/) module.

With the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views/) module installed and enabled, visit Site Administration -> Structure -> Views -> Add New View (`admin/structure/views/add`)

And without going into too much [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views/) detail, use a similar configuration to the screenshot below.

[image: Views Configuration]

Comment: Hi @citricguy,  Thanks. I had already done something similar.  The problem is the access control.   Even doing the way you mentioned above as an anonymous user (not logged) I can still see the list of files and download them.   The content type is marked as private is there anything in the view itself or in the drupal that I should do?